# MSSQL/TSQL separating fields into rows based on value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables with data like:

table: test_results

```
ID  |test_id    |test_type  |result_1   |amps       |volts      |power      |
----+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
1   |101        |static     |10.1       |5.9        |15         |59.1       |
2   |101        |dynamic    |300.5      |9.1        |10         |40.1       |
3   |101        |prime      |48.9       |8.2        |14         |49.2       |
4   |101        |dual       |235.2      |2.9        |11         |25.8       |
5   |101        |static     |11.9       |4.3        |9          |43.3       |
6   |101        |prime      |49.9       |5.8        |15         |51.6       |
```

and

table: test_records

```
ID  |model      |test_date  |operator   |
----+-----------+-----------+-----------+
101 |m-300      |some_date  |john doe   |
102 |m-243      |some_date  |john doe   |
103 |m-007      |some_date  |john doe   |
104 |m-523      |some_date  |john doe   |
105 |m-842      |some_date  |john doe   |
106 |m-252      |some_date  |john doe   |
```

and I'm making a report that looks like this:

```
                                               |static                                         |dynamic                                        |
test_id    |model      |test_date  |operator   |result_1   |amps       |volts      |power      |result_1   |amps       |volts      |power      |
-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
101        |m-300      |some_date  |john doe   |10.1       |5.9        |15         |59.1       |300.5      |9.1        |10         |40.1       |
```

with left outer joins like so:

```
SELECT
    A.ID AS test_id, model, test_date, operator,
    B.result_1, B.amps, B.volts, B.power,
    C.result_1, C.amps, C.volts, C.power
FROM
    test_records A
LEFT JOIN
    test_results B
ON
    A.ID = B.test_id
    AND
    B.test_type = 'static'
LEFT JOIN
    test_results C
ON
    A.ID = C.test_id
    AND
    C.test_type = 'dynamic'
```

But I have run into a problem. The "static" and "prime" tests are run twice.
I don't know how to differentiate between them to create their own 4 fields.
An abstracted(simplified) view of the desired report would look like:

```
|static     |dynamic    |prime      |dual       |static2    |prime2     |
|4 fields   |4 fields   |4 fields   |4 fields   |4 fields   |4 fields   |
```

Is this even possible? 
Notes:

1. I'm labeling the groups of 4 fields with html so don't worry about the labels
2. Not every test will run "static" and "prime" twice. So this is a case of If ("static" and "prime") are found twice, do this SQL.
3. I think we're going to get our engineers to append a 2 to the second tests, eliminating the problem, so this question is more out of curiosity to know what method could solve a problem like this.

Comment: The "4 fields" is an abstraction. It would literally be sql output of 4 separate fields. No extra work is needing to be done to make some kind of comma separated list. Each group of 4 fields is associated with a test_type. See the third code-block in my post for the un-abstracted version.

Comment: There are 2 record `101 & static` in `test_results` table How do you want to show them?

Comment: You could use a column `test_sequence` to distinguish the same `test_type` carried out multiple times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have another field (here I use ID) that you know is always going to be ordered in respect to the field you can use a windowing function to give them sequential values and then join to that.  Like this:

```
WITH test_records_numbered AS
(  
   SELECT test_id, test_type, result_1, amps, volts, power, 
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY test_id, test_type ORDER BY ID) as type_num
   FROM test_records
)
SELECT
    A.ID AS test_id, model, test_date, operator,
    B.result_1, B.amps, B.volts, B.power,
    C.result_1, C.amps, C.volts, C.power
FROM test_records A
LEFT JOIN test_records_numbered B
      ON A.ID = B.test_id AND B.test_type = 'static' and B.type_num = 1
LEFT JOIN test_records_numbered C 
      ON A.ID = C.test_id AND C.test_type = 'dynamic' and C.type_num = 2
```

I use a CTE to make it clearer but you could use a sub-queries, you would (of course) have to have the same sub-query twice in the SQL, most servers would have no issue optimizing without the CTE I expect.

I feel this solution is a bit of a "hack."  You really want your original data to have all the information it needs.  So I think it is good you are having your app developers modify their code (FWIW).

If this had to go into production I think I would break out the numbering as a view to hi-light the codification of questionable business rules (and to make it easy to change)

Comment: There are a few minor bugs in your example, but this was the solution I was looking/hoping for. Thanks for showing me the CTE solution and listing the alternative. bugs : no FROM in the CTE. JOINs are using a different name than the CTE.

Comment: @van I fixed the FROM issue but it looks like they are joining to `test_results_numbered` so I don't see the 2nd typo.

Comment: test\_**records**_numbered and test\_**results**_numbered. These are always the kinds of typos that make me facepalm after an hour of debugging lol

Comment: @van -- dang... totally did not see that.  SQL should know records and results are the same thing :D